# how to replace a true value based on column name and additional table?

Tags: r

I have the following data. `v1:v4` are boolean (TRUE/FALSE)

df1

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4
1  T  T  F  F
2  F  F  T  F
3  T  F  F  F
4  F  T  T  T
```

df2

```
var weight
v1   1
v2   4
v3   2
v4   5
```

I require to first replace the `TRUE` value of each variable based on the variable name and the secondary  table `df2`. So any `TRUE` under `V1` column, for example, will become `1`. `FALSE` will always be `0`.
Later, the status variable will define whether the entire row contains a single non-zero value or multiple

df.out

```
id v1 v2 v3 v4 Status
1  1  4  0  0  Multiple
2  0  0  2  0  Single
3  1  0  0  0  Single
4  0  4  2  5  Multiple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  Loop `across` the column names specified in 'var' column of 'df2', `replace` the `TRUE`values by the corresponding 'weight' element by `matching` the column name (`cur_column()`) with the 'var' column.  Then, we create a the 'Status' column based on the number of non-zero elements per each row using `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(across(df2$var, 
     ~ replace(., .,  df2$weight[match(cur_column(), df2$var)]))) %>%
    mutate(Status = case_when(rowSums(.[df2$var] > 0) > 1 
         ~ 'Multiple', TRUE ~ 'Single'))
```

-output

```
 id v1 v2 v3 v4   Status
1  1  1  4  0  0 Multiple
2  2  0  0  2  0   Single
3  3  1  0  0  0   Single
4  4  0  4  2  5 Multiple
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1new <- cbind(df1[1], setNames(df2$weight, 
           df2$var)[col(df1[df2$var])] * df1[df2$var])
df1new$Status <- c("Single", "Multiple")[1 + (rowSums(df1new[df2$var] > 0) > 1)]
```

-output

```
> df1new
  id v1 v2 v3 v4   Status
1  1  1  4  0  0 Multiple
2  2  0  0  2  0   Single
3  3  1  0  0  0   Single
4  4  0  4  2  5 Multiple
```

---

Or another option is `Map` from `base R`

```
lst1 <- Map(`*`, df1[df2$var], df2$weight)
cbind(df1[1], lst1, Status =  c('Single', 'Multiple')[1 + (rowSums(df1[-1]) > 1)])
  id v1 v2 v3 v4   Status
1  1  1  4  0  0 Multiple
2  2  0  0  2  0   Single
3  3  1  0  0  0   Single
4  4  0  4  2  5 Multiple
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, v1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), v2 = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), v3 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), v4 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(var = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"), weight = c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be very simple by matrix operation `x` is `df1` and `y` is `df2`

```
x <- matrix(c(T,F,T,F,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,T), nrow =4 , ncol = 4)
y <- c(1,4,2,5)
z <- x %*% diag(y)
z
```

result is

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    0    0
[2,]    0    0    2    0
[3,]    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    4    2    5
```

letting

```
Status<- x %*% diag(y)  %>%  as.logical(.>0) %>% matrix(.,4,4) %>% rowSums 

res <- cbind(z,Status) %>% as.data.frame

  V1 V2 V3 V4 Status
1  1  4  0  0      2
2  0  0  2  0      1
3  1  0  0  0      1
4  0  4  2  5      3
```